# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render with custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I keep getting a "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" error using custom  hook return values in my component

The hook looks like this

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const { REACT_APP_BASE_PATH } = process.env;

axios.defaults.baseURL = REACT_APP_BASE_PATH;

export const useAxios = (axiosParams, deps = []) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async (params) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.request(params);
      setResponse(result.data);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(axiosParams);
  }, [...deps]);

  return { response, error, loading };
};

export default { useAxios };
```

The component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Box, Button, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import { useAxios } from '../../helpers/hooks';
import { accountsListColumns, renderItems } from '../../helpers/constants';
import useStyles from '../styles';

export const SingleAccountPage = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const classes = useStyles();

  const {
    response = [],
    error,
    loading,
  } = useAxios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `/account/findOne${search}`,
  });

  if (loading) return <CircularProgress />;
  if (error) return <h1>{error}</h1>;

  return (
    <Box className={classes.singlePageWrapper}>
      <Box className={classes.singlePageHeader}>
        <Typography variant={'h4'}>Account: {response.id}</Typography>
        <Button
          variant={'contained'}
          onClick={() => history.goBack()}
          className={classes.singlePageBackButton}
        >
          Go back
        </Button>
      </Box>
      {renderItems(accountsListColumns, response)}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

So basically those 2 lines cause the problem for some reason

```
  if (loading) return <CircularProgress />;
  if (error) return <h1>{error}</h1>;
```

In the future, I want to conditionally render an error and loading component, but for now even this doesn't work for some reason.

In the error messages, it says

```
index.js:1 Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by SingleAccountPage. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useContext                 useContext
2. useContext                 useContext
3. useContext                 useContext
4. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
5. useContext                 useContext
6. useRef                     useRef
7. useRef                     useRef
8. useRef                     useRef
9. useMemo                    useMemo
10. useEffect                 useEffect
11. useEffect                 useEffect
12. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
13. useState                  useState
14. useState                  useState
15. useState                  useState
16. useEffect                 useEffect
17. undefined                 useContext
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

`Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: this is really weird. I suggest you try to create a minimal reproducible example in codesandbox & produce the same error there(it would help you & us, to narrow down the issue). you kinda got me interested to find out what the problem is. currently, in the code you provided, I don't see any. (there's nothing wrong with your early return statements, so although removing it is solving the problem, it's probably not the core issue here). currently, my only suspicion is the useStyles hook you're importing. can you share the code for that or maybe comment it out to see what happens?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4):

This problem is normally caused by an early `if` statement. Basically for all renders, you need to have same number of hooks registered, and same order of hooks registered.

But a brief look of your code seems nothing wrong, your `if` statement is right above `return` statement. And you already narrow down the issue statement.

```
  if (loading) return <CircularProgress />;
```

The debug message actually already tell us everything, thanks for attaching that, i never actually see this message before. Very kool.

The last line

```
17. undefined                 useContext
```

It says you supposed to have a `useContext` which is used by `CircularProgress` but this time you don't. `useContext` is used mostly for a theming purpose.

##### Solution

now we know what happened, let's see if we can solve it

```
  const spinner  = <CircularProgress />

  return (
    <>
     {loading && spinner}
     {!loading && (
        ... your rest of render ...
     )}
    </>
```

This way it's always rendered, but only based on your condition, it's displayed or not.

##### Solution Improved

Of course this solution defeat the flow of your code, the early return makes your code very neat, but now it's not any more, we have to cover both `loading` or not conditions.

In order to remedy on that, maybe go back to your old way.

```
  const spinner = <CircularProgress />
  if (loading) return spinner
  if (error) return <h1>{error}</h1>;

  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Unfortunately, the error still persists, although now the spinner is being rendered for a split second and after that, I get the same error.
I also get an error when I comment out the spinner and leave only if error statement, but now it says fewer hooks are rendered, than before

Comment: replace `CicularProgress` with a `<div>spinner</div>`, see if you still run into problem. If you still run into problem, then this has nothing  to do with spinner :)

Comment: Yeah, still persists =(

Comment: Then it's not a spinner problem :) haha. You can go comment out more code, step by step, until you get back to a case that is working.

Answer (score 3):

There's a super easy fix to this. Move all of the functions, hooks above the return statement, everywhere. So that all of the hooks are rendered before the return statement. This might not be good for performance, but it sure is a work-around at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a useEffect in `<CircularProgress/>` this could cause the problem, since it only renders if `loading` is `true`. Since initially loading is undefined.

Comment: If I use comment out if loading statement and the error one is left, I get an error "rendered fewer hooks than expected" =(
Not sure about `<CircularProgress/>` having useEffect, since it is just a material ui spinner  component